# Firebase in app messaging stopped working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Firebase InAppMessaging stopped working. As it was working from one month.

i updated the pod, previously FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay was 0.13.1 and now it’s 0.15.5

As there isn’t any single line of code for that just followed this steps

https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=ios

As i can able to get instance id, previously i can able to test on simulator as well as device

but now i didn’t Please help

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/878

Comment: Whoever vote down the Question, Please kindly explain the reason. As there isn't any code for in App Messsaging, it's just an steps that I have followed.

Comment: Did you run your project with the -FIRDebugEnabled flag? Please update your post with the message Firebase will log to the console when you send an InAppMessage. It will look something like this:
[Firebase/InAppMessaging][I-IAM180017] Seeing test message in fetch response. Turn the current instance into a testing instance.